# Explain the reason for Ambiguous column error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Business_Unit`:

```
    business_unit_id    int
    area_code           nvarchar(100)
    region_code         nvarchar(100)
    sub_region_code     nvarchar(100)
```

It has some values in it.

Query 1:

```
select 
    business_unit_id,* 
from 
    business_unit 
order by 
    business_unit_id desc
```

When I query this, i get the following error.

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Ambiguous column name 'business_unit_id'.

To solve, I've used the alias name for the table as bu and prefixed the column with the alias name.

```
select 
    bu.business_unit_id, * 
from 
    business_unit bu 
order by 
    bu.business_unit_id desc
```

Even the below query works.

```
select 
    bu.business_unit_id, bu.* 
from 
    business_unit bu 
order by 
    bu.business_unit_id desc
```

I would like to know, why it threw an error[business_unit_id], with query "Query 1". There is no ambiguity here, I only have one table.

Can you explain?

---

the reason for asking this question.
I have a 120 column table (assume bigtable), now, I want to order it by let say 90 column. I cannot scroll and check the value, hence I put select 90thcolumn,* from bigtable order by 90thcolumn.

---

Comment: Are you sure `Business_Unit` is a `Table` and not a `View` ???

Comment: 100% , its a table :)

Comment: good question.even this work ,select col2,* from tbl1 order by tbl1.col2 .so here what is the difference guys ?how do you explain this ?

Comment: Please have a look I have updated my answer with a bit more explanation and I hope this will clear the clouds :)

Comment: Also for my case, if i've a big table, and if i wanted to sort by the 90th column and ofcourse, if i dont want to scroll, i'll put the 90th column as the first column in the select query and order by 1st column. here is the query. Select 90thcolumn,* from bigtable order by 1 desc.(again i got the answer from one of the replies). Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right I think I have found some explanation for this weird behaviour

IF you only do something like this

```
SELECT Column1, * FROM Table_Name
```

this should work ok.

But when you do something like

```
SELECT Column1, * FROM Table_Name 
ORDER BY Column1  --<-- this Column1 is contained in `*` as well as in the SELECT
                     -- statement too, SQL Server needs to know which one to use
                     -- in your order by clause.
```

It will throw an error as Column1 is being SELECTED twice in you SELECT Query and SQL Server wants to know by which column you want to order by your Results .

Ambiguous column  is in your Order by clause but not in your Select statement.

**Further Explanation**

Further to prove my point the following is the order in which SQL directives get executed.

> 1. FROM clause
> 2. WHERE clause
> 3. GROUP BY clause
> 4. HAVING clause
> 5. SELECT clause
> 6. ORDER BY clause

As you can see the SELECT operator is executed before the ORDER BY clause. therefore in your case SELECT clause will have two columns with same name, and when it comes to ORDER BY the results SQL Server want to know which column to use in your ORDER BY and it throws the error of `Ambiguous column`.

When used with alias the Ambiguity is resolved and you get no more errors.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted.    select 
    bu.business_unit_id, bu.* 
from 
    business_unit bu 
order by 
    bu.business_unit_id desc. Above query is still ambiguous, but it doesnt throw an error in this case. one of the person who replied told that, we can cheat, SQL Server, by using alias name. When alias name is used, SQL Server doesnt care.

Comment: Also for my case, if i've a big table, and if i wanted to sort by the 90th column and ofcourse, if i dont want to scroll, i'll put the 90th column as the first row and order by 1st column. here is the query. Select 90thcolumn,* from bigtable order by 1 desc.(again i got the answer from one of the replies)

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are using the `*` wildcard which returns all rows. Change your query to...

```
Select * from business_unit order by business_unit_id desc;
```

And by the way, you can actually "cheat" sql server by using aliases

Comment: i've a 120 column table, now, i want to order it by let say 90 column. i cannot scroll and check the value , hence i put, select 90thcolumn,* from bigtable order by 90thcolumn.

Comment: It makes sense what you are saying. Your options are...using aliases as in your 2nd query or just return the columns you are interested in

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error `Ambiguous column name 'business_unit_id'` because of order by clause. sql server allows to include two column with same name included in a query (without join).

So order by clause is not able to identify which column to use while sorting because it's able to see two columns with same name.

Answer (score 1):

@M.Ali's answer explains the problem well one work around is to alias just the column, no need to alias the entire table:

```
select 
    business_unit_id bid,* 
from 
    business_unit 
order by 
    business_unit_id desc
```